# Property does not exist on object - Angular

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I have an object, which I want to fill and use the `description` property

```
public obj = {};
  setObj(){
    this.sp.getResourceUrl(this.results[0].resource_url).subscribe(data => {
      this.obj = data; // data has description property
    });
  }
```

It worked fine for a while with the following html code but somehow the error "The property description does not exists on type {}"

```
    <div *ngIf="obj && obj.description != ''; else notfound">
        {{obj.description}}
    </div>
    <ng-template #notfound>
        <div>
            Description not found.
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

Do I have to set all properties I receive from the object I get via GET-Request? If yes, why? It worked fine before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typescript warning to you but a fine javascript code.

Yes, you should ideally define type of properties you are using in your classes, this way it helps to mitigate unseen errors which can happen during runtime. For example if you are accessing `{{obj.description}}` instead of `{{obj.descriptions}}`, typescript warns you before hand rather than you finding it at runtime that there is no `description` on `obj`

You can have an Interface or a type for these props.

Here for example, it should be:

```
public obj: {descriptions?: string} = {}; // add more keys if you get more keys hetre
```

One way to bypass your errors would be to type it as `any`

```
public obj: any = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following code

```
<div *ngIf="obj && obj.description; else notfound">
    {{obj.description}}
</div>
<ng-template #notfound>
    <div>
        Description not found.
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

i.e. it will display if and only if `obj` and `obj.description` will exist otherwise `notfound` will be displayed

Answer (score 1):

You are just checking for `obj` availability and not its `description`.

As this line `public obj = {};` says, `obj` is just an empty object in the first and `obj.description` is `undefined`.

So you should first check for the `description` availability and then check the value or etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is check for null or undefined (to see whether the object exists) using safe navigation operator

```
 <div *ngIf="obj && obj?.description != ''; else notfound">
```

Also make sure you are defining the type if you already know it, or use any

```
 this.sp.getResourceUrl(this.results[0].resource_url).subscribe((data : any) => {
      this.obj = data; // data has description property
    });
```